# App Service unavailable for unknown reason

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We're running App Service for Linux in docker container.

When things work, they work really good. But, occasionally, our site becomes unavailable for unclear reason.
Our health status reports looks like this:

[image]

Now, after some time, the app becomes completely unavailable. Health check reports Available, but in out docker log we find records like this:

```
2017-11-18 08:01:50.060 ERROR - Container for --- site ---is unhealthy. Stopping site.
2017-11-18 08:32:49.295 INFO  - Issuing docker login to sever: http://---
2017-11-18 08:32:49.837 INFO  - docker login to http://--- succeeded
2017-11-18 08:32:49.858 INFO  - Issuing docker pull ---
2017-11-18 08:39:49.096 INFO  - docker pull returned STDOUT>> 40: Pulling from ---
```

The only thing that helps is restarting the app. Then it comes back to normal and all works as expected.

I emphasise, site doesn't hang on every 'Unavailable' report from the Health check. It hangs randomly. CPU/Memory are at normal levels, nothing unusual there and no crasy spikes.

Application itself has general exceptions filter and no uncaught exceptions go out of app.

Any ideas why it might happen?

Comment: would downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the site of your docker image, the application goes offline while it's pulling and initializing the new image. I noticed that our deploy took nearly 20 minutes before coming back up.

Comment: You should post comments in the "comments" section below the question.

Comment: @StanislavPoslavsky it looks like I'm not there on my account yet to be able to do that.